# imagePickerViewController is not dismissed when an overlay button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have implemented an custom camera overlayView with a button to access the photoLibrary using a UIViewController class with xib file. The overlay loads successfully and the button works fine. However, the camera is still open in the background when the photoLibrary is open. It seems like the photoLibrary View is just covering the camera view, I can even click where the "shoot" button was supposed to be and take pictures... Does anyone know whats the problem here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you implement a custom overlay view, it is your responsibility to dismiss the UIImagePickerController. This is from the `showsCameraControls` property on UIImagePickerController

`If you set this property to NO and provide your own custom controls, you can take multiple pictures before dismissing the image picker interface.`

You must call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` on the UIImagePickerController from the `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` delegate method.

Comment: But does the imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: method invoke when I press the "select" button on the overlayView? because all i did was presenting another UIImageController, nothing gets picked yet.